# Unable to get the right graph from OSM when using Osmnx in just a specific location (Modena)

Tags: openstreetmap, networkx, osmnx

My goal is to generate routes from point A to point B using Osmnx and Networkx. Routes represent walking and cycling displacements, so I want to ignore one-way streets.

In order to accomplish this, I am using the argument: `G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='walk')` and everything has worked perfectly until now for Barcelona (ES) and Cesena (IT).

Now I am trying to do the same with Modena (IT), but I get an incomplete graph when using both `network_type='walk'` `network_type='cycle'` (see png attached).

The only way to get the complete Modena graph is to not specify the `network_type` argument, but by doing this edges in G still bring the value `oneway = True`. Therefore, the routing is incorrect, because it takes into consideration oneway streets. I have tried to change that value using:

```
for u, v, key, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    data['oneway']=False
```

I do not receive any error, but the routing is still incorrect. 
What am I missing here?

[Modena graph with no roads in city centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ysTw.png)
[expected routing vs wrong routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv5Wc.png)

**EDIT: Attached the code snippet that:**

- retrieve the graph without specifying the network type and plot
  it with oneway streets in red
- retrieve the graph with network type = walk and plot it
- List the missing OSMids and plot them in magenta

  ```
  place = {'city' : 'Modena', 'country' : 'Italia'}

  #--------SOME BASIC SETTINGS FOR PLOTTING------

  one_way = (0.863, 0.039, 0.173,1)
  two_way = (0.243, 0.243, 0.243,1)
  background = (0.973, 0.973, 0.973,1)


  #--------PLOT GRAPH WITHOUT SPECIFYING THE NETWORK TYPE AND GET THE OSMIDs---------

  G = ox.graph_from_place(place)

  osmid_no_network = list([data['osmid'] for u, v, key, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)])

  ec = [one_way if data['oneway'] else two_way for u, v, key, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)]

  fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor=background,
  show=False, close=True, fig_height=11, fig_width=11, node_size = 0, edge_linewidth = 0.1, edge_color = ec, dpi=300)
  fig.suptitle("Modena_no_network_type")
  plt.show()
  ox.plot.save_and_show(fig, ax, save=True, show=False, close=True, filename = "Modena_no_network_type",
  file_format="png", dpi=300, axis_off=True)


  #--------PLOT GRAPH SPECIFYING THE NETWORK TYPE = WALK AND GET THE OSMIDs-------

  H = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type = 'walk')

  osmid_network_walk = list([data['osmid'] for u, v, key, data in H.edges(keys=True, data=True)])

  ec = [one_way if data['oneway'] else two_way for u, v, key, data in H.edges(keys=True, data=True)]

  fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(H, bgcolor=background,
  show=False, close=True, fig_height=11, fig_width=11, node_size = 0, edge_linewidth = 0.1, edge_color = ec, dpi=300)
  fig.suptitle("Modena_network_walk")
  plt.show()
  ox.plot.save_and_show(fig, ax, save=True, show=False, close=True, filename = "Modena_network_walk",
  file_format="png", dpi=300, axis_off=True)

  #--------GET THE OSMIDs LIST OF MISSING EDGES AND PLOT MISSING EDGES IN MAGENTA---------

  missing_edges = [i for i in osmid_no_network + osmid_network_walk if i not in osmid_no_network or i not in osmid_network_walk]
  print(missing_edges)

  m_edges = (0.859, 0.180, 0.938, 1)
  ec2 = [m_edges if data['osmid'] in missing_edges else two_way for u, v, key, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)]

  fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor=background,
  show=False, close=True, fig_height=11, fig_width=11, node_size = 0, edge_linewidth = 0.1, edge_color = ec2, dpi=300)
  fig.suptitle("Modena_missing_edges")
  plt.show()
  ox.plot.save_and_show(fig, ax, save=True, show=False, close=True, filename = "Modena_missing_edges", file_format="png", dpi=300, axis_off=True)
  ```

EDIT: added Retain_all png
[Modena retain all true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpqSM.png)

EDIT: reduced the [bbox area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVvYr.jpg) to downtown and created [list of missing edges](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NRFn5_BI0X4gyT2yR2jwj8aWzdEjPOhqr6SdeHhXlhQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide a complete intact code snippet to reproduce what you're doing? And also a list of OSM IDs of the edges you believe are missing from the resulting graph?

Comment: I have edited my post with the snippet: it also prints the list of missing edges and plots them on a third image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are downloading two different network types: `walk` and `all_private` (which is the default), so you get different networks. The edges don't appear to be missing, they appear to be either 1) non-walkable edges or 2) part of a disconnected graph component (since you have `retain_all` set to its default `False`.

Comment: It looks like a bit of both 1) and 2). I attached the graph when `retain_all = True`, and I get some more disconnected edges, but still a number of edges are not displaying (this is downtown and almost car free: should this be addressed to OSM?). Do you think using the `Network_type='drive'` (which seems the most complete) and force all the edges to be `one_way = false` makes sense?

Comment: If you provide the OSM IDs of the some of the missing edges, I can inspect them to see if they should appear in the `walk` graph.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I restricted the area (see png) and created the list of the missing edges (plotted in magenta). Those streets should definitely be walkable...

Comment: Looking at the [first osmid](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/190606078) in your list of missing edges you can see that it is tagged as access=private. Hence it is retrieved if you set `network_type='all_private'` but not when you set `network_type='walk'` as the latter filter is designed to retrieve *public walkable* paths. You can also construct your own custom filter for fine tuning: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html?highlight=custom_filter#osmnx.core.graph_from_place

Comment: Thanks again! I will try to create a custom filter to solve the problem in the next few days.